# How to make a background cover a separate div?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I'm doing a site with side-menu. 30% of the screen is the menu and the rest is content.

The contents of the div, I put a background image using the COVER method. I used the first example:
 https://css-tricks.com/examples/FullPageBackgroundImage/css-1.php

However, this method works perfectly when the image occupies the entire background. As in my example, I want the same exact occupy 70% of the width, "eats" the image corners.

How can I fix this?

HTML:

```
<div id="esquerda" style="width: 30%; height: 500px">
 ....conteudo.....
</div>

<div id="direita" style="width: 70%; height: 500px">
   <img src="fundo.jpg" class="bg">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bg {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;

    width: 100%;
    height: auto;   

    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    float: right;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
     .bg {
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -512px; 
     }
}
```

Comment: That's a strange way of doing it. I would rather use a CSS-Background (`background-image: url(fundo.jpg)` if that is OK for you)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basic approach using `background-image` and 3 different elements (to prevent xBrowser issues related mostly to Safari)
setting the background to `cover` on the `#bg` layer element

```css
*{ box-sizing: border-box;}
html, body{ height:100%; }
body{ position:static; margin:0; }

#bg{
  background: url('http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg') 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  width: 70%;
}
#menu{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0; top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 30%;
  background: rgba( 0, 0, 255, 0.4 );
}
#page{
  position: relative;
  border: 10px dashed #000;
  margin-left: 30%;
  width: 70%;
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg">BG</div>
<div id="menu">FIXED</div>
<div id="page">SCROLLABLE</div>
```

on top of that code you can apply CSS3 **media queries** as you please.

***Note*** that the "easiest" would be *not* to use the separate `#bg` element but instead to set the bg image directly to the `#page` element using  `background-attachment: fixed;` but, as mentioned, the image might not appear on Safari in combination with it's size set to `cover`.

Comment: I tried to make some changes using the fixed and relative position, but without success. His example is very simple, objective and easy understanding. Thanks, helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

use the `background-image` attribute in your CSS. You can create a separate class to use in the CSS that only has that attribute.

```
.bgImage {
    background-image: url("fundo.jpg");
}
```

then apply the class to the `<div>` tag.

```
<div id="direita" class="bgImage" style="width: 70%; height: 500px">
   ...    
</div>
```

Comment: It is good practice that I need to take. Tip annotated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's do it the easy way - use the CSS `background-image: url("fundo.jpg");` on the div's style.